# How can i create a instance and add the instance to another class in python

Tags: python, class, oop

It is my second-day learning object-oriented programming.
I have a code which when I create a instance it should automatically be added to another class.
The way Iam asking may be wrong so apologies.

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        
class Owner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = []
```

How should I modify the classes above so that when a new instance of `Pet`
is created, it is automatically added to its `Owner's` list of
pets.
for example: if I created the instances below

```
owner_1 = Owner(Name("Daenerys", "Targaryan"))
owner_2 = Owner(Name("John", "Snow"))

pet_1 = Pet(Name("Drogon", "Targaryan"), owner_1)
pet_2 = Pet(Name("Viserion", "Targaryan"), owner_1)
pet_3 = Pet(Name("Rhaegal", "Snow"), owner_2)
```

Owner.pets will return a list of pets of an owner
i.e for Daenerys, the list will be ["Drogon Targaryan", "Viserion Targaryan"]

Comment: I am not sure what to find for the internet it would be helpful if I am pointed to a link that would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last


class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        self.owner.add_pet(self)


class Owner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = []

    def add_pet(self, pet):
        self.pets.append(pet)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it same way except adding self to add_pet :(